# GCP ops agent fluentbit logging level defaults to info

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform

I am running GCP ops agent installed as per google documentation (https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/ops-agent/installation) and I'm stuck at finding out why my logs are not sent from the VM to stackdriver.
I followed GCP documentation troubleshooting guide and had no luck.
It seems that ops agent is trying to send logs via fluentbit to stackdriver but for some unknown reason it fails to do so.

```
  "stackdriver.1": {
    "proc_records": 0,
    "proc_bytes": 0,
    "errors": 1,
    "retries": 0,
    "retries_failed": 0,
    "dropped_records": 71,
    "retried_records": 0,
    "stackdriver_successful_requests": 0,
    "stackdriver_failed_requests": 1
  }
}
```

I was trying to find out how to set fluentbit's  log level to debug but every time I change the setting under `/var/run/google-cloud-ops-agent-fluent-bit/fluent_bit_main.conf` at restart it gets overwritten and it defaults to info.
Did anyone have this issue in the past or do you have any tips I can try to fix the logging agent's logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to check for permissions issues by executing request to logging API manually from the VM.
Here is the example request you can run with curl:

```
export PROJECT_ID=<your project_id>
curl https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:write \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
--data-binary @- << EOF
{"logName": "projects/$PROJECT_ID/logs/test-log",
  "entries": [
    {
      "logName": "projects/$PROJECT_ID/logs/test-log",
      "textPayload": "test text from VM",
      "resource": {
        "type": "gce_instance",
        "labels": {
          "test": "test"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
```

If it doesn't work - most probably there is something wrong with permissions. If it works - need to further debug logging agent.

Comment: Hi @Oleksandr, Indeed I have some permission issues. Thanks for suggesting this.

Comment: After setting the apt permissions required for resolving the issue did it encounter again ?